# KB968730 after Server 2003 SP2 already installed

Tags: windows-server-2003, outlook, hash

Our company already has Server 2003 SP2 installed, and with it brought crypt32.dll version 5.131.3790.5014. We're still, however, having what I believe are SHA2 errors (see below). Some preliminary research suggests that KB968730 should resolve this, but its version number is lower (5.131.3790.4477). Any suggestions?

Error 1: When launching Outlook 2007 from a Server 2003 box, receive error "The application experienced an internal error loading the SLL libraries. This site should not be trusted."

Error 2: When looking at the certificate itself, says "The integrity of this certificate cannot be guaranteed. The certificate may be corrupted or may have been altered." It's issued by Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, and valid till 2016.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file is on the QFE branch.  If it is on RTM or GDR then you need to push it to QFE to make the bug fix effective.